# LaserJet M15a not printing from network

Tags: networking, printing, hp

I have an HP LaserJet Pro M15a connected to my Ubuntu 22.10 Server via USB.  The printer is shared and prints nicely from the server's command line.  When I try to print from my laptop (also Ubuntu 22.10) the printer is discovered but never prints.  This has been going on for a week or two; previously I was able to print from the laptop with no difficulty.  I don't recall any changes that affected the server or the laptop.  How can I restore this capability?

Further details upon request.

Comment: From the server provide outputs for `lpstat -t` and `systemctl status ipp-usb`.

Comment: $ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: LaserJet_M15a
device for HP_LaserJet_M15a_103F7B_USB: implicitclass://HP_LaserJet_M15a_103F7B_USB/
device for LaserJet_M15a: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_M14-M17?serial=VNB3R14066
HP_LaserJet_M15a_103F7B_USB accepting requests since Mon 06 Mar 2023 08:06:22 PM EST
LaserJet_M15a accepting requests since Sun 05 Mar 2023 02:42:25 PM EST
printer HP_LaserJet_M15a_103F7B_USB is idle.  enabled since Mon 06 Mar 2023 08:06:22 PM EST
printer LaserJet_M15a is idle.  enabled since Sun 05 Mar 2023 02:42:25 PM EST

Comment: $ systemctl status ipp-usb
● ipp-usb.service - Daemon for IPP over USB printer support
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ipp-usb.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-03-05 14:02:30 EST; 1 day 6h ago
       Docs: man:ipp-usb(8)
   Main PID: 3886 (ipp-usb)
      Tasks: 12 (limit: 18935)
     Memory: 9.4M
        CPU: 408ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ipp-usb.service
             └─3886 /sbin/ipp-usb udev

Mar 05 14:02:30 grace.koalatyworks.com systemd[1]: Started Daemon for IPP over USB printer support.

Answer (score 0):

> device for HP_LaserJet_M15a_103F7B_USB: implicitclass://HP_LaserJet_M15a_103F7B_USB/

This device is auto-setup by cups-browsed. It uses [IPP-over-USB](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting) via ipp-usb. ipp-usb needs to be told to expose the printer on the network. Edit **/etc/ipp-usb/ipp-usb.conf** to have **interface = all**. Then do `systemctl restart ipp-usb`.

Comment: Okay, I tried that.  Interface was set to loopback, so I reset it to all, as you said, but I still can't print a test page from my laptop.  Do I need to reboot the server or something for the change to take effect?

Comment: @Ken Wright I have added to my answer.

Comment: I restarted ipp-usb.  Now I see a new printer when I try to add one through Ubuntu's Settings, but it fails to be added.  The new printer says it's HP_LaserJet_M15a_103F7B_USB, but like I said it fails to add.  The existing printers pointing to the LaserJet also refuse to print, with the print jobs marked "pending."

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try printing from the laptop with `lp -d "HP_LaserJet_M15a_103F7B_USB" /etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: "lp: The printer or class does not exist."  So just for fun I tried lp -d "LaserJet_M15a_grace" /etc/nsswitch and the job is pending.

Comment: The job is still pending.